# Common abstract class for plugins

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have a few plugins and intend to move them to a very common base with an abstract class.
The issue is that even if I apply solutions in order to avoid class duplications ( like [EarnestoDev](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/8211/earnestodev)'s answer for [#31034](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31034/theme-and-plugins-sharing-common-libraries) ) the system could end up with different versions of the abstract class if more of my plugins are present.

In order to avoid this I should update all my plugins when the abstract class is updated, but that seems to be an overkill.

Is there any other way to include classes only for a specific plugin rather than using [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no system in WordPress to handle dependencies and sharing components between extensions is a challenge.

The possible solutions roughly are:

- make shared part a plugin and require each plugin to require it (and possibly auto install/activate)
- implement loader that will take care of processing versioning for shared part and take care of loading latest version available (see [scbFramework](https://github.com/scribu/wp-scb-framework) for one example of such)

If extensions are for private use (as opposed to being separately and publicly available) you can manage them as part of whole site stack - in version control or Composer (which I hope will get more traction for WP projects).